# Something like bash -x in nodes

Tags: node.js, bash, debugging

Is there something like the bash option -x  in node js ?

It is rather useful to just get a dump of what my process is doing especially when I don`t know where my process is hanging up .

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is Node's `debugger`: http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

On its own, running `node debug <script>` will let you see what's going on. You can also set enter `debugger` statements in your code, that stop the code and let you examine the program state. Also, there are other features such as watchers and breakpoints - see the URL above for  full documentation.

Comment: well aware of it, I'm looking for something that prints the trace none interactive like the bash -x option . I am sorry I was not more clear to the specific facet of what I was interested in .

Comment: But `node debug <script>` on its own just shows the program working, isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes, exactly the information I am looking for .  I would though like the dump to be saved to a log no interactively for review as if I had stepped through the stack manually , just like bash -x does ; )